# troubles with dns configuration

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-11.04

My server's ip is 192.168.1.1

I was trying to configure dns with bind9. But:
When I use `nslookup 192.168.1.1` I've got as a result

```
 server:  192.168.1.1
 address: 192.168.1.1#53
 **server can't find 1.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa:SERVFAILE
```

when I use `nslookup guf.by` I've got as a result

```
 server:  192.168.1.1
 address: 192.168.1.1#53
 **can't find guf.by:no answer
```

My /etc/bind/named.conf.local

[image: name.conf.local]

/etc/bind/named.conf.options

[image: name.conf.options]

I can ping myself with domain name - so ping `ubuntu.guf.by` is working.(ubuntu my server's name. client can ping server by domain name too)
My /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
[image: dhcpd.conf]

And my /etc/network/interfaces
[image: interfaces]

Both rev.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa and guf.by.db are in catalog `zones`
resolv.conf

```
search guf.by
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

SERVER DOESN'T PING CLIENT by domain name!

Comment: What is the contents of your /etc/resolv.conf file?

Comment: `search guf.by nameserver 192.168.1.1` and that's all

Answer (score 0):

First, is bind (named) running?  Are there any fw/iptables rules that blocks tcp/udp port 53?

Try checking /var/log/messages for any bind/named errors.  If there were any issues with the data files, you should see something in the log file.

It looks like the ubuntu's IP address is 192.168.1.1.  In your named.conf, you list the forwarder to 192.168.1.1.  If you intend to run bind on 1.1, you don't need to setup a forwarder to itself.

If you defined the local hostname as "ubuntu.guf.by", then you'll be able to ping yourself.  Check out /etc/hosts, you might see an entry for "ubuntu" or "ubuntu.guf.by" to 127.0.0.1 or 192.168.1.1